# php unable to redirect correctly

Tags: php, html

I have the following php code named recover.php:

```
<?php

include "php/init.php";
inaccessible_if_loggedIn();

if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {

?>
    <p>succes!</p>

<?php
} else {

    $allowed_modes = array('username', 'password');
    if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'], $allowed_modes) === true) {

        if (isset($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['email']) === false) {

            if (user_in_DB($_POST['email'])) {
                // TO DO: schrijf recover functie
                //recover($_GET['mode'], $_POST['email']);
                header("Location: recover.php?success");
                exit();
            } else {
                $errors[] = "email: " . $_POST['email'] . " does not exist";
            }

        }

        include "includes/recover_form.php";
    } else {
        header("Location: includes/errorPages/page_not_exist.php");
        exit();
    }

}


?>
```

the html include contains a form with action recover.php

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signInStylesheet.css">
    <title>bestBay</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header_container">
        <a id="logoLink" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="register_form">

        <div class="formBody">

            <form action="recover.php" method="post">

                <br/>

                <span class="formText">E-Mail<span style="color: red">*</span></span> <input name="email" class="fillInput" type="email" maxlength="90" required>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <?php echo print_errors($errors); ?>

                <input class="signInButton" type="submit" value="Recover">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

page layout:

[image: html layout]

The problem is after the user enters a valid email my php code still redirects to "includes/errorPages/page_not_exist.php" as if the ?succes after the link is not there.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong in my code.
If I leave

```
else {
        header("Location: includes/errorPages/page_not_exist.php");
        exit();
    }
```

empty my code seems to work.
What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: `isset($_GET['mode']) === true` is `false`.

Comment: I don't see where `$_GET['mode']` is being set.

Comment: oh the mode is set in another html when clicking on a link. But the thing is after the `header("Location: recover.php?success")` my code shouldn't even test for the `$_GET['mode']` anymore because the `if (isset['success'])` returns true

Comment: It's not getting as far as redirecting to the success page, so `$_GET['mode']` is checked, and is not set as your form action doesn't set a GET variable.

Comment: Why do you have so many php tags in your code? please remove these tags and echo success...?>
    <p>succes!</p>

<?php

Comment: In my Opinion, the Problem lies at this line:
isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true

you should check what $_GET['success'] holds. And if it really is empty or not

Comment: where do u set the $GET?

Comment: I see @JonStirling that was such a simple mistake. Leaving my action = "" empty in the form solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have so many php tags in your code? please remove those tags and echo success also try using elseif for the second part of your code...

?>

succes!

include "php/init.php";
inaccessible_if_loggedIn();

if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {

```
echo succes!;
```

} elseif {

//please also log your errors on the starting line using ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: I think they are unnecessary to use them in that way while they can just echo the response

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather simple. My code never got as far as even redirecting to the success page. This was because my form action never passed a GET variable resulting in $_GET['mode returning false'].

The simple solution was to just leave the action empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signInStylesheet.css">
    <title>bestBay</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header_container">
        <a id="logoLink" href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="register_form">

        <div class="formBody">

            <form action="" method="post">

                <br/>

                <span class="formText">E-Mail<span style="color: red">*</span></span> <input name="email" class="fillInput" type="email" maxlength="90" required>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <?php echo print_errors($errors); ?>

                <input class="signInButton" type="submit" value="Recover">
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```